# Variable set with the aid of BB_ORIGENV isn't seen in another recipe

Tags: build, bitbake, openembedded

I have recipe A.bb in meta-layer-X:

```
python () {
origenv = d.getVar("BB_ORIGENV", False)
origenv.setVar("IsImageMiniBuild", True)
}
```

and recipe B in meta-layer-Y which is parsed later (this one I debugged and for sure B is executed later than A):

```
python () {
IsImageMiniBuild= d.getVar("BB_ORIGENV", False).getVar("IsImageMiniBuild", True)

import re
if IsImageMiniBuild:
    #do sthm
else:
    #do sthm other
}
```

The problem is that variable IsImageMiniBuild is not seen in B.bb. Why and what to do in order it is seen? According to bitbake documentation it should be seen.
Maybe it has to be exported somehow?
In A.bb when I get back variable it is set, so setting is done well.

Answer (score 0):

Where in the documentation does it say that works? BB_ORIGENV is a copy of the original environment, not a global data store.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it seems like not right description of BB_ORIGENV in documentation or my bad understanding of description.
Is any possibility to pass information between recipe A from layer X to recipe B from layer Y? I was thinking about creating file or variable in local.conf when recipe A is processing. But I worry about consequences. Let's say user will build some other target which doesn't include A and include B (1). Let's say user will build target which includes both A and B (2). Then let's say the order is opposite, firstly user build (2) then (1). Without clearing manually file/local.conf variable there will different results of building recipe B in case (1). For me there is lack in bitbake some global environment variable which is always cleared at start. I though BB_ORIGENV is such variable which doesn't store information between two build cycles.
Probably I should define my global variable which is cleared always at build start (whatever target is built). But I don't have idea how to do this, what is entry point in bitbake where I have some access and could set variable empty.